# Popupcontact form body backgroud

Tags: javascript, html, popup

Could you please help me with the code below?

When the popup opens, I want the body to blurred or grey transparent with less opacity.

```
$(function() {
  
    // contact form animations
    $('#contact').click(function() {
      $('#contactForm').fadeToggle();
     
    })
    $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
      var container = $("#contactForm");
  
      if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
          && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
   
      {
          container.fadeOut();
      }
    });
    
  });
```

I tried to add `$("body").css("opacity","0.25");` to change only the opacity, but the form is also changed...

HTML is:

```
<div id="contact">Contact</div>

<div id="contactForm">

  <h1>Keep in touch!</h1>
  <small>I'll get back to you as quickly as possible</small>
  
  <form action="#">
    <input placeholder="Name" type="text" required />
    <input placeholder="Email" type="email" required />
    <input placeholder="Subject" type="text" required />
    <textarea placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
    <input class="formBtn" type="submit" />
    <input class="formBtn" type="reset" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide the html too?

Comment: Sure, I just added it.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, what do you mean by "popup"?

Comment: This contact form appears only when I click on <div id="contact">Contact</div>. When it appears I want the background of the whole website (but this form) to change color/opacity.